# JavaScript - hours, minutes, seconds, millisecond to floating point seconds for html audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I need to convert a string with hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds "hh:mm:ss:mil" to the floating-point number that HTML audio player uses for currentTime.

I can't find any conversion algorithm that does this! The closest I've found converts to seconds as integers, while I need something like this

"00:00:38:000" -> 38.0 (NOT 2280)

"01:15:02:773" -> 4502.773

**My Code so far - but it's wrong**

```
function time2secs(time) {
    // 00:03:30 -> 3.5 seconds
    var t = time.split(':');
    if (t.length < 4) t[3] = 0; // if a missing millisecs, then set it to 0

    var seconds = parseInt(t[0]) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(t[1]) * 60 + parseInt(t[2]) + parseInt(t[3]) / 1000;

    return seconds / 60;
}
```

Comment: // 00:03:30 -> 3.5 seconds ???

Comment: As a float I guess, this is what it returns for currentTime from the audio player at that time! That should be the output when given string "00:03:30" / "hh:mm:ss" returns float of 3.5

Comment: but in minutes?

Comment: You're right! That's a mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function timeToSec(time){
    var arr=time.split(":");
  return parseInt(arr[0])*3600+ parseInt(arr[1])*60+ parseInt(arr[2])+ parseInt(arr[3])*0.1000
}
console.log(timeToSec("00:00:38:000" ))
console.log(timeToSec("01:15:02:773" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work as you expect?

```js
function time2secs(time) {
    var t = time.split(':');
    if (t.length < 4) t[3] = 0;

    let second = (parseInt(t[0]) * 60 * 60) + (parseInt(t[1]) * 60) + parseInt(t[2]) + (parseInt(t[3]) / 1000);
    return t[3] == 0 ? second + ".0" : second;

}
```